# ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';' 31 | require(balance0f(from) >= value, 'balance too low';

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I'm getting this error when trying to compile:

> ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';' --> gabicoin.sol:31:56: | 31 | require(balance0f(from) >= value, 'balance too low'; | ^

Below is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Gabicoin {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 250000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "Gabicoin";
    string public symbol = "GBC";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    event transfer(address indexed from, adress indexed to, uint value);
    event approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balance0f(adress owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balancef(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferfrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balance0f(from) >= value, 'balance too low';
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[from] -= value;
    emit transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
}
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool){
    allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(balance0f(from) >= value, 'balance too low';
```

Should be

```
require(balance0f(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
```